# Two MySQL while loops not working properly [PHP]

Tags: php, mysql

I have two while loops, both through MySQL results, see code:

```
        $result1 = $sql->runQuery1();
        $result2 = $sql->runQuery2();

                    while($record1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
                    {
                        echo "$record1['id'] : ";
                        while($record2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
                        {
                            echo "$record2['id'] <br> ";
                        }
                    }
```

Above code will run inside loop only once, code below:

```
        $result1 = $sql->runQuery1();


                    while($record1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
                    {
                        $result2 = $sql->runQuery2();
                        echo "$record1['id'] : ";
                        while($record2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
                        {
                            echo "$record2['id'] <br> ";
                        }
                    }
```

above will run internal loop as many times as many records is in MySQL query. Is there more efficient way of looping through that data? I don't want to re-run query each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you fetch your result in an array, you should get all results. I suggest for PHP using `$results = $sql->runQuery1()` which will let you iterate through your results in a loop:

```
foreach($results as $var) {
    $var->doStuff(); // or display or whatever
}
```

you can of course nest these

```
foreach($results as $var) {
    foreach($results2 as $var2) {
        $var->doStuff($var2); //for example
    }
}
```

Here's the manual: http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.foreach.php

The fetch_array and fetch_assoc will give you all fields in a row from your query into an associative array.

Comment: how do i read MySQL column from $var then? When I do $var['price'] I get error Warning: Illegal string offset 'price'

Comment: Use fetch_assoc, it gives you an associative array with values like `{key => value}`with key being the column name. I will edit my answer, hold on.

Comment: If you use fetch_array you'll have to read your values by key/index (`$value = $var[0]` where your index is the order of columns in your table starting with 0)

Comment: if I did exactly as you show: echo $var['quote_id']; i get an error: Warning: Illegal string offset 'quote_id' in /var/www/html/index.php on line 138

Comment: I may have gotten some of the syntax mixed up, it's been a while. Refer to this: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: so foreach($sql->runQuery2() as $var) does work, but it will query database with each parent loop, which i don't want to.

Comment: got solution, just don't run mysqli_fetch_assoc() at all, loop through foreach($results2 as $var) That works :) you can edit your answer and i will accept it

Comment: Yeah, I derped, fetch_assoc is for a single row only, not for a fully result set.

Comment: in answer delete mysqli_fetch_assoc(), change it to $result = $sql->runQuery1(); $result2 = $sql->runQuery2(); and then foreach($results2 as $var) that works spot on